# Ionic 2 In App Browser opening all links with header (back button)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am currently trying to open all links with the InAppBrowser plugin from cordova.
This is my code:

```
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen, GoogleAnalytics, InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';

declare var window: any;
declare var cordova: any;

initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
    Splashscreen.hide();
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        console.log('is cordova');
        window.open = (url, target?, opts?) => {
        console.log('window.OPEN CALLED');
       (new InAppBrowser(url, '_blank', 'location=yes'));
       };
    }
}
```

My links are opening in the in app browser, but without the header. So I cannot close the in app browser in iOS because there is no back button.

Can anyone help out? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try using '_system' as target. All available options are : '_self', '_target', '_system'

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Would you have another idea?

Comment: Please take a look at the options object at https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/#InAppBrowserOptions. Note the 'fullscreen', 'closebuttoncaption' or 'toolbar' properties.

Comment: Could it be possible there is something wrong with my code? with the window.open => newInAppBrowser?
Because I never get the console.log

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Comment: Was there a solution to this?

Comment: I unfortantly havent. Have you got the same problem?